# I created an android notification channel_id in Flutter, however, sending FCM to that channel does not result in vibration or sound

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created an android notification channel by using the flutter_local_notification package with the following code:

```
await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin()
  .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  .createNotificationChannel(AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
  ));
```

When I request the current notification channels that my app use, I get the newly created (and a few others) back as a result, so the creation worked.

However, when I send a notification with FCM to the newly created channel, that notification does not make a sound or vibration. If I send the same notification to a channel that was already there, I do get a sound and vibration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the mistake is in the `importance` parameters.

```
importance: Importance.max
```

should be

```
importance: Importance.high
```

`Importance.max` is not used by Android, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_MAX)

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to manually play sound and vibrate in onMessage/onBackgroundMessage/onBackgroundMessage using [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) and [flutter_vibrate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vibrate)